# Use Control Send and Control Click In AutoIT to Automate Background Processes

Tags: automation, autoit

I'm having Issue getting AutoITv3 to send a Control Down key stroke to a background program using the ControlSend function. I've been successful in getting the ControlClick function to work as shown below.

I've tried using both the ClassnameNN and the Class as the Control ID, both Failed. I've also attempted to add the "0 flag" as the last argument just in case the default was somehow changed.

**Current Script**

```
$wPos = WinGetPos("[Conquer] Raiding Clans")
WinActivate("[Conquer] Raiding Clans")

Sleep(2000)
ControlSend("[Conquer] Raiding Clans","","[CLASS:#32770]","{CTRLDOWN}")
ControlClick("[Conquer] Raiding Clans","","[CLASS:#32770]","left",1,$wPos[0] + 60 , $wPos[1] + 150)
```

**AutoItv3 Window Info Tool Summary**

```
>>>> Window <<<<
Title:  [Conquer] Raiding Clans
Class:  Afx:400000:0:10007:0:0
Position:   160, 136
Size:   1600, 768
Style:  0x94000000
ExStyle:    0x00000000
Handle: 0x019B16EE

>>>> Control <<<<
Class:  #32770
Instance:   1
ClassnameNN:    #327701
Name:   
Advanced (Class):   [CLASS:#32770; INSTANCE:1]
ID: 
Text:   
Position:   0, 0
Size:   1600, 768
ControlClick Coords:    105, 295
Style:  0x50000044
ExStyle:    0x00040000
Handle: 0x00381172

>>>> Mouse <<<<
Position:   265, 431
Cursor ID:  0
Color:  0x9FA8AA

>>>> StatusBar <<<<

>>>> ToolsBar <<<<

>>>> Visible Text <<<<
??
CSConceal
Prefix1
Prefix2
Prefix3
Prefix4
Prefix5
Prefix6
Prefix7
Prefix8
Prefix9
Prefix10
Prefix11
Prefix12
Prefix13
Prefix14
Prefix15
Prefix16
Prefix17
Prefix18
Prefix19
Prefix20
Prefix21
OpenVip
????
Close
OUTCHAT
OK
S
C
C
A
L
LOG
A
??
??
??
??
??
?
??
??
??
??
??
PK
???
?
??
?
btn
Equipment
Draw
CSMore


>>>> Hidden Text <<<<
XP1
XP2
XP3
XP4
XP5
XP6
XP7
XP8
XP9
XP10
U
D
Progress1
?
Progress3
Progress1
Progress2
Progress1
```

The expected function of this script would be for the script to hold down control and then click at a given set of coordinates.

Comment: Does it work if you do it like this: activate the window, then send the command and then put it back in background?

Comment: @Xenobiologist
I tried using WinActivate to active the client as suggested, I then used WinActive to verify it was active. Still no dice. I've posted the code below. The code was added after the Sleep on line 4.


`WinActivate("[Conquer] Raiding Clans")

MsgBox(0,"",WinActive("[Conquer] Raiding Clans"))`

Comment: When you open a MsgBox, what do you think is the active Window?

Comment: The MsgBox output of WinActive read as the Handle for the [Conquer] Raiding Clans Program 0x000B343C. So it does activate it and still successfully does ControlClick, but fails to use the ControlSend  CTRLDOWN command.